# How to highlight a particular word in a paragraph

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js MVC as my front end together with html,bootstrap. I am trying to display results as per the search keyword(ng-model).
My requirement is in such a way, in the results that are displayed, I need to highlight the search keyword in the result.

My content is displayed inside `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html

```
 $scope.highlight = function(haystack, needle) {
        if(!needle) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(haystack);
        }
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(haystack.replace(new RegExp(needle, "gi"), function(match) {
            return '<span class="highlightedText">' + match + '</span>';
        }));
    };
```

css

```
.highlightedText {
    background: red;
}
```

html

```
<div ng-bind-html="highlight('Nic is cool and smart', 'and')"></div>
```